# Zend navigation menu set class appears across both calls

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have set up zend_navigation to work with my array of menu items and can make a call to my menu as follows:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

However, i have a menu, and a menu editor on a page so have two calls to this in order to generate another ul which can be reordered as neccesary.

My issue comes when i try to add a class to the 'sortable' menu using

```
->setUlClass('sortable')
```

which adds the class as expected, but to **both** of the calls to create the menu. The calls are as follows:

**navigation.phtml:**

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu();
```

**index.phtml**

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->setUlClass('sortable');
```

But they both inherit the class 'sortable'.

Anybody know any possible reason for this, as i thought a new call would create a new instance of the navigation menu to render..?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple as described on [this chap's blog](http://blog.kaning.co.uk/archives/216).

The thing to do is render the second menu as exactly that - render it.... E.G. render it not use the default menu() method. This way, you tell the Zend_Navigation element to 'spit out' the result and not treat it as being a set property of itself - if that makes sense.

The key part from the link above is this bit:

```
$options = array('ulClass' => 'submenu');
echo($this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($this->miscnavigation, $options));
```

Which, in your instance can be reworked to:

```
echo($this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu($this->navigation()->getContainer(), array('ulClass' => 'submenu')));
```

Which can be used in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Try to echo them like that:

```
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu();
echo $this->navigation()->menu()->renderMenu(null, array('ulClass' => 'sortable'));
```